Filter VertexAI Search results to 1 result per domain
I recently migrated my custom search with site restrictions to Vertex AI Search. This was the document guide I followed.
Everything is functioning as expected, however, I can't find the option to "Filter similar results" in the discovery engine SDK. This is a screenshot of the toggle in Programmable Search Engine

Here is my Python code calling the discoveryengine_v1 sdk
client = discoveryengine.SearchServiceClient(
            client_options=ClientOptions(api_endpoint=api_endpoint)
        )
serving_config = client.serving_config_path(
    project=project_id,
    location=location,
    data_store=data_store_id,
    serving_config="default_config",
)

request = discoveryengine.SearchRequest(
            serving_config=serving_config,
            query=search_query,
            page_size=page_size,
            spell_correction_spec=discoveryengine.SearchRequest.SpellCorrectionSpec(
                mode=discoveryengine.SearchRequest.SpellCorrectionSpec.Mode.AUTO
            ),
            safe_search=True,
        )
client.search(request)

This is for a search app with a general websites data store.
Would it be possible to recreate the "Filter similar results" using boosting/filtering or even better, restrict the results to one result per domain? How would this be done?
Thanks!
